# Entity adds new IDs instead using existing one

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, list

How can I attach entire list or loop through it without null reference error?

Entity classes

```
public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Product_Id { get; set; }
        public string Product_Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }       
    }

public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int Category_ID { get; set; }
        public string Category_Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

List from CheckBoxList

```
 IList<ListItem> prodCat = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (ListItem item in cblCategory.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            prodCat.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Adding new product

I've tried to attach Categories - see comment

```
        public void AddProduct(string prodName, IList<ListItem> prodCat)
    {
        ProductDBContext productDBContext = new ProductDBContext();
        Product prodNew = new Product();
        prodNew.Product_Name = prodName;

        List<Category> categList = new List<Category>();
        foreach (ListItem item in prodCat)
        {
            Category categObj = new Category
            {
                Category_Name = item.Text,
                Category_ID = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value)
            };
            categList.Add(categObj);
          //  prodNew.Categories.Add(categObj);  //Null reference
        }
        prodNew.Categories = categList;
        productDBContext.Products.Add(prodNew);
        productDBContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: `Adding new product with error message` what the error message  says?

Comment: Cannot convert type System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>” on „System.Collections.Generic.IList<ProductsApplication.Category>”

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your actual problem is. The title states that EF created new objects instead of existing ones. But later you ask how to bulk create new objects without reference error. It seems your question isn't clear to me. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var categories = prodCat
    .Select(p => new Category
    {
        Category_ID = p.Value,
        Category_Name = p.Text
    }
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Wrong variables. Edited my answer.